# Find an unkown from matrix representation of linear tranformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ where $V=(\Bbb{Z}_3)^3$ over $\Bbb{Z}_3$.

The linear transformation is **not** invertible and is represented by the matrix:

$$ [T]_B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & a & 2a \\ a & 1 & 2a\end{pmatrix}$$

Where $B=((1,0,2),(0,1,1),(1,0,1))$.

I need to figure out what $a$ is, I solved it by seeing that $\det[T]_B=0$ and solving the equation which gave me $a=1$.

My question is, how can I solve such problems in a more "generic" way, for example, lets say, for some transformation $S:V\rightarrow V$, $\det[S]_B\ne0$.

I tried to look for a way to solve some sort of a matrix and come up with an equation that will let me figure out what $a$ was but I didn't manage to find a way.

So, Is there a generic way to solve such problems without relaying on the type of transformation or basis?

Comment: If the title is misleading or I didn't make myself clear in it, please edit it and I'll approve or let me know what's wrong and I'll try to fix it, thanks.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question from what you've written. Here, you're given some additional information about $T$ that lets you determine $a$, namely that it is singular. If $[S]_{B}$ is some matrix depending on a parameter $a,$ you would need some additional information about $S$ or some extra property you would like the matrix to satisfy in order to formulate an equation to determine $a.$

Comment: @RideTheWavelet So you are saying that without the information about $T$ being singular, I wont be able to determine what $a$ is? This is what I am looking for, a way to solve that kind of question without relaying on extra information (like $T$ is singular)

Comment: @RideTheWavelet If I am still vague please let me know, I'll try my best to rewrite my question

Comment: This is exactly what I'm saying. You can have a family of matrices (or linear operators) depending on a parameter (or you can think of this as a function from the parameter space to the space of matrices/linear operators), but that's all you have without an extra condition. It's like considering the function $f(x)=x^{2}$ and asking what $x$ is, at least from how I'm understanding what you're saying.

Comment: @RideTheWavelet Alright I got it, I didn't think of it that way but thanks to you I manage to understand what I was asking and why its not possible. Basically I need to pay attention to those information in order to solve the problem